# Change meta title tag and open link in new tab on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook

I want to share a link on Facebook after the user has been asked a question on the webpage. The user will be asked "Do you like XYZ". Then, I want to display an option at the bottom of the page to share on Facebook. To share a link on Facebook is

```
window.open("www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=window.location.href&t=document.title", "_blank");
```

and replacing the page's meta description should be something like this?

```
('meta[property="og:title"]').replaceWith('<meta property="og:title" content="SHARE THIS">');
```

But I can't seem to combine these into one button.

For instance, the code below is my attempt at doing this and it does not work (absolutely nothing happens).

```
<button>SHARE</button>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$('button').on('click', function() {
    $('meta[property="og:title"]').replaceWith('<meta property="og:title" content={{ result }}>');

    $window.open("www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://localhost/&t=document.title", "_blank"); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: not working means what happens?? fb share not working or OLD meta title going to fb share

Comment: @RanaGhosh neither one works haha. Nothing happens when I click the button.

Comment: first add alert inside button click, and check slert is showing or not

Comment: And what is {{ result }} holds in your. And check console that after clicking on giving any error or not

Comment: @RanaGhosh I added $alert('meta[property="og:title"]'); -- and it is not doing anything at all. The {{ result }} was a placeholder for the result of the user action

Comment: Replacing OG meta tags on the client will have no effect on the share; the Facebook scraper does not execute any client-side JavaScript.

Comment: @CBroe then how is Buzzfeed doing it? I just shared a URL from one of their quizzes https://www.buzzfeed.com/perpetua/heres-9-questions-to-determine-if-youre-more-type-a-or-type and it showed up in Facebook

Comment: Either by using the Feed dialog, that sill allows to specify those extra parameters at runtime, or by sharing individual URLs with GET parameters that let the server identify a certain result and output the corresponding meta data.

Comment: @CBroe do you know of a stackoverflow question that explains how to do this on button click?

Comment: Which one? How the Feed dialog works, is explained here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog

Comment: @CBroe thanks, I can easily use that in place of the code above, but I still need to get the updated page title

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have a syntax error in you script. `window.open` doesn't need `$` sign.
So, just replace your `JS` code with mine and it will works if you the correct **URL** in yor `{{ result }}`. Please follow below code::

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$('button').on('click', function() {
    $('meta[property="og:title"]').replaceWith('<meta property="og:title" content={{ result }}>');

    window.open("www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://localhost/&t=document.title", "_blank"); 
});
</script>
```

Additional Ref::

[Window.open syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

But be carefull, how can you share any localhost **URL** in **FB share**, unless and untill it's not on server.

Comment: Also alert not required $ symbol before

Comment: I actually added the $ before the window.open because window.open was not working. This code, for me, still doesn't work.

Comment: But in my end there already opening a new tab with FB share URL

Comment: So, something else other than this piece of script must be causing it to not show up. Maybe it is because I have two buttons on the pag?e?

Comment: I'm not sure how to change $('button') to an ID selection?

Comment: <button id="fb_share">SHARE</button> || SCRIPT:: $('button[id="fb_share"]').on('click', function() {

Comment: Still nothing is happening at all, with new IDs etc

Comment: Not even opening a new tab?

Comment: Nope, nothing happens at all